# How do I stop my activities from becoming garbage when multitasking?

Tags: java, android-studio

I was getting some crash reports from users after I launched a update. Only a few users reported this crash. Later, a user told me he only gets the crash when he leaves the app, opens it back and presses a button.

Originally I thought that when a application is multitasking, android simply keeps it running in the background.. to my surprise it seems like the java garbage collector is kicking in and destroying my activity calling onDestory(). After this is called, a reference to another object becomes null which is why the app crashes after "that" button is pressed (null error).

How can I stop android activities from being destroyed while multitasking? Why are my activities even being destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you cannot stop your activities from being destroyed in the background.**

This is what the "don't keep activities" developer option is for. Your activities must save their state in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState`.  Turning on "don't keep activities" allows you to test that those methods are working correctly.  If your app doesn't work with "don't keep activities" on, then your app doesn't work.

The garbage collector has nothing to do with this. The Android framework decides when an activity is going to be destroyed and calls `onDestroy` on it. An activity only becomes eligible for garbage collection when there are no more references to it.